# Erros when i create a new android project

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

My eclise refuses to let me create new android projects. When i create a new (default) project, even if i don't change anything, i get these errors in these lines.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //activity_main cannot be resolved
```

and

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); //main cannot be resolved
```

And if i add an element to the layout, my project can't use the strings in the string.xml anymore. These problems started yesterday. Before yesterday there were no problems like this. Please help me.

Comment: check for `import android.R;`

Comment: Theses are the errors i get when i add import android.R;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes its create a problem while we are starting Eclipse... And we have opened our project in eclipse.

SO you have to just follow:

**Project**->**Clean**->**Run**

This is Because you have imported **R.java** file by default of Eclipse.

You should again check **Project**->**Clean**->**Run**

and then import your R.java file as a **yourPackegeName.R;** not as a **android.R;**

Comment: I thoth to have resolved the problem, but now, even if i clean the project, the same errors are still there